# How to add additional column in Problems view in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

In the Eclipse *Problems* view, is there a way to add additional column (i.e *Justify*)?

My motive is to add additional problems marker attribute, in which I should be able to add a justification to the intentionally created problems which will be displayed in this additional column.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you can do this by using the [`org.eclipse.ui.ide.markerSupport` extension point](https://help.eclipse.org/photon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fextension-points%2Forg_eclipse_ui_ide_markerSupport.html) to define a new `markerField`, which will correspond to a new column in the Problems View.